# Does QuickFIX/N support messages containing two components with one group each, both with same name?

Tags: fix-protocol, quickfixn

I am using QuickFIX/N 1.8 and when it has to create the DataDictionary based on an XML, it fails because my **FIX50SP1_TRTN.xml** (provided by Thomson Reuters) contains one message (`AllocationReport`) with two components (`TrdInstrmtLegGrp`, `InstrmtLegAllocGrp`), and both components have a group with a same name (`NoLegs` - `555`).

QuickFIX/N is trying to create a dictionary per message, containing the groups of all its components, where the key of each group is the id.
Therefore, it's trying to insert the key `555` twice, throwing an Exception the second time.

System.ArgumentException: 'An item with the same key has already been added.'

**\QuickFIXn\DataDictionary\DataDictionary.cs**

```cs
else if(childNode.Name == "group")
{
    DDField fld = FieldsByName[childNode.Attributes["name"].Value];
    DDGrp grp = new DDGrp();
    XmlAttribute req = childNode.Attributes["required"];
    if (req != null && req.Value == "Y"
    && (componentRequired == null || componentRequired.Value == true))
    {
        ddmap.ReqFields.Add(fld.Tag);
        grp.Required = true;
    }
    if (!ddmap.IsField(fld.Tag))
    {
        ddmap.Fields.Add(fld.Tag, fld);
    }
    grp.NumFld = fld.Tag;
    parseMsgEl(childNode, grp);
    ddmap.Groups.Add(fld.Tag, grp); //########### It fails when the second group is processed ###########
}
```

Summarized content of my **FIX50SP1_TRTN.xml**

```xml
<fix major="5" minor="0">
  <header/>
  <trailer/>

  <messages>
    <message name="AllocationReport" msgtype="AS" msgcat="app">
      <component name="TrdInstrmtLegGrp" required="N"/>
      <component name="InstrmtLegAllocGrp" required="N"/>
    </message>
  </messages>

  <components>
    <component name="TrdInstrmtLegGrp">
      <group name="NoLegs" required="N"> <!-- 555 -->
         (content A)
      </group>
    </component>
    <component name="InstrmtLegAllocGrp">
      <group name="NoLegs" required="N">
         (content B)
      </group>
    </component>
  </components>

  <fields>
    <field number="555" name="NoLegs" type="NUMINGROUP"/>
  </fields>
</fix>
```

My questions:

1. Is QuickFIX/N supposed to support this situation?
2. Have you ever faced this problem? How did you solve it?
3. Do you know some explicit constraint (in QuickFIX/N, or the FIX protocol itself) about this situation? (maybe there is an explicit restriction saying that a message cannot contain more than one component with a group with a same name).

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this is not allowed by the FIX specification. I say this because the FIX 4.4 and FIX 5.0 specification documents both state:

> A tag number (field) should only appear in a message once. If it appears more than once in the message it should be considered an error with the specification document.

In addition, if you search through a FIX specification document or a FIX data dictionary file for `PartyID`, you will see that the *concept* of a repeating group containing `PartyID`, `PartyIDSource` and `PartyRole` appears in several places, but each with different names for the repeating group and the fields it contains. There are:

- `NoPartyIDs`
- `NoNestedPartyIDs`
- `NoNested2PartyIDs`
- `NoNested3PartyIDs`
- `NoNestedParties4`
- `NoDerivativeInstrumentParties`
- `NoInstrumentParties`
- `NoRootParties`
- `NoSettlPartyIDs`
- `NoTargetParties`
- `NoUndlyInstrumentParties`

All of those repeating groups contain three fields denoting a party ID, its source and its role, but the names of those fields is never reused from one repeating group to another, and the same repeating group is not used more than one in a message. For example, the `ExecutionReport` message contains:

- `NoPartyIDs`
- `NoNestedPartyIDs`
- `NoNested2PartyIDs`
- `NoNested3PartyIDs`
- `NoNestedParties4`

There are a few other cases of structurally-similar-but-differently-named repeating groups in FIX.

My point is that if FIX intended to allow a repeating group to appear multiple times in a message, then there would not have been any need for FIX to define structurally-similar-but-differently-named repeating groups in the FIX specification.

I suggest you raise this concern with Thomson Reuters. I once encountered a similar issue with a different trading venue; it turned out I had been given a buggy draft version of the venue's FIX specification, and they were happy to send me an up-to-date, corrected version of their FIX specification.

Comment: Awesome answer, very helpful.  Somehow I missed this in the spec.  Santiago, this is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is an open issue, [which I myself discovered last September](https://github.com/connamara/quickfixn/issues/495).

<strike>I'm fairly sure that this DD situation is allowed in FIX, meaning this is a QF/n problem.  (I'd wager money that some of the other QF language ports have this problem too.)</strike>  **Update: Per Ciaran McHale's excellent answer, this is *not* allowed in FIX.**

I do intend to fix this, but I can't say when it'll happen.  **Update: Even though it's not allowed in FIX, I still want to support it in QF/n because counterparties do stupid things.**

I don't have a good workaround right now.  In my case, I was lucky that we didn't actually use that message in the application that I was developing, so I could just comment that problem group out of the DD.

Comment: Interesting answer by Ciaran, pointing out that using the same ID more than once isn't allowed by the FIX standard specification.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, TT.  Ciaran pretty much nailed it.  However, counterparties violate the spec all the time, so it still probably wouldn't hurt to add this support in anyway.

Comment: Perhaps using a special configuration flag to allow this.

Comment: No flag needed.  Once it's implemented, there's no great reason to ever not allow it.

Comment: @Grant Birchmeier: I'm not sure it is a good idea for a FIX product to support this non-compliant behaviour for a tag of type `NUMINGROUP`, because it might open a can of worms. For example, if you provide such support, then are you also going to provide similar support for a tag whose type is not `NUMINGROUP`? And is such support going to be provided only for what is in a FIX data dictionary file? Or also for what appears in a transmitted FIX message?

Comment: My thinking is purely practical.  To my knowledge, at least 2 counterparties are doing this, so it's a need.  (In my experience, counterparties don't often care if they're doing FIX wrong.)  I know that I can fix the DD parser and message parser to support it.  This would only be allowed with a DD (because you can't have repeating groups without one, of course).  Plus, I'm fairly sure this already works for tags that are not NUMINGROUP, provided the tags are in different groups.

But let's not get too excited.  I'm not promising to do this anytime soon....

Comment: An alternative approach would be as follows. Contact counterparties who are violating the FIX specification in their data dictionaries and ask them to fix the problem in their data dictionaries. If they so do, then the problem is solved. If they decline to do so, then you can make a copy of their data dictionary and modify it to fix the problem. This approach is likely to involve a few orders of magnitude less work than modifying a FIX product so it can cope with broken data dictionaries.

Comment: I have experience trying to tell counterparties that they are wrong, and it doesn't always work :) . Beyond that, I don't think you can fix their DD to sidestep the issue; if they're going to send you a message that re-uses a group-counter-tag, I can't think of a way to hack your local DD to accept that.  If I could, I would be the first person to recommend it, and I would have answered this question with it.

Comment: @CiaranMcHale I must admit that I've complained with counterparties, with different success. One changed ExecutionReport messages (invalid tags included), another declined to change their ExecutionReport messages (invalid transition of order state). It's a pain. Especially if you have one code base that needs to serve different flavors (misinterpretations really).

Comment: Grant and TT, thanks for describing your experiences of working with counterparties. I have worked with about 25 counterparties, and have encountered this type of problem with only one, and even that turned out to be due to an out-of-date, draft specification document. The other problem that TT mentions (invalid transition of order state) is something I have encountered more frequently, and have dealt with it (painfully at times) in application-level code.