# FIX repeating groups to reuse same tags

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj

Does FIX protocol allow to reuse same tag in a message and in repeating groups? I.e. could I have something like that

```xml
        <message name='Quote' msgtype='S' msgcat='app'>
            <field name='Price' required='Y'/><!-- i.e. total price for the whole quote-->
    ...
            <group name='NumLegs' required='Y'>
                <field name='Price' required='Y'/><!-- i.e. leg price -->
    ...
                <group name='NumLegDetails' required='Y'>
                    <field name='Price' required='Y'/><!-- i.e. leg component price -->
    ...
                </group>
    ...
            </group>
        </message>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TL;DR

It is **not** allowed *in the tag-value encoding*.
(but in *FIXML* it is)

### Some explanations

My initial misunderstanding came from this statement in the FIX tag-value specification: [see here, search for "Field presence"](https://www.fixtrading.org/standards/tagvalue-online/#message-structure)

> A tag (field) must appear at most once in a message, except when the
> tag appears within a repeating group.

But as I learned this refers to the *wire* format of the message, not the *definition* of the message.

Whereas the FIX5.0SP2 spec Volume 1 refers to the *definition* of the message and states:

> A tag number (field) should only appear in a message once. If it
> appears more than once in the message it should be considered an error
> with the specification document.

In the meantime I even found it mentioned in FIXimate when looking at the `NestedParties` component (emphasis mine): ([link to NestedParties component in FIXimate](https://fiximate.fixtrading.org/legacy/en/FIX.5.0SP2/body_49484856.html))

> The NestedParties component block is identical to the Parties Block.
> It is used in other component blocks and repeating groups when nesting
> will take place resulting in multiple occurrences of the Parties block
> within a single FIX message.. **Use of NestedParties under these
> conditions avoids multiple references to the Parties block within the
> same message which is not allowed in FIX tag/value syntax.**

BTW, there are also components `NestedParties2`, `NestedParties3`, `NestedParties4` to work around this.

### Information from FIX Trading Community Forum

The thread can be accessed here, but as far as I know you can only access it if you are a FIX TC member: [FIX TC forum](https://forum.fixtrading.org/t/multiple-occurrences-of-a-tag-within-a-message/15475?u=christophjohn)

The FIX expert [Hanno Klein](https://www.fixdom.de/about/) gave the following information:

> The quote from the refactored online spec refers to the wire format of
> any instance of a message encoded in tagvalue syntax. It means that
> *inside* the wire format of a *single* repeating group a tag (field) may
> appear more than once.

FIXML does not have this restriction:

> The restriction is actually limited to the tagvalue encoding. For
> example, the parties component is “Pty” for all instances in FIXML,
> the XML syntax/encoding of FIX. This is due to the fact that the XML
> syntax has an unambiguous structure with a distinct path to every
> occurrence of a component or field. The XML names only need to be
> unique within the same element.

Tag-value does:

> For tagvalue, a parser needs to know when a repeating group starts and
> ends. The NoXXX field marks the starting point and a field that is not
> part of the group marks the ending point. There are no explicit
> delimiters for repeating groups in tagvalue and components
> (non-repeating) are not visible in the wire format at all.
> Technically, you are probably right that a Price tag could exist in
> two distinct repeating groups without causing a parser issue but I do
> not see the benefit to allow this exception to the rule. You cannot
> allow it for two adjacent levels, e.g. root + nesting level 1 or
> nesting level x + nesting level y.

---

### This part from original answer still applies

On another note, when defining your own repeating groups please use the notation `NoXXX` for repeating groups since that is the official recommendation. [see here, search for "NumInGroup field"](https://www.fixtrading.org/standards/tagvalue-online/#message-structure)

> It is recommended that NumInGroup fields be named NoXXX, e.g.
> NoContraBrokers(382).

However, following your example with `44/Price` you would normally see `566/LegPrice` used as the price for an individual leg since the two are used differently. The former is the price used for the execution of an order, the latter is used when defining a leg of a strategy.

So in short, when defining your message structure and repeating groups you should really think about if the meaning of the tag is the same for all occurrences of the tag in the message <strike>and if it really makes sense to use the very same tag in the body and in repeating groups.</strike> Clarity should be first priority.

---

### incorrect (strike through) part of original answer

<strike>At first I thought that this could not be allowed but mainly because I have never seen it appear somewhere in a real message. But actually I could not find a reason why it should not be allowed.</strike> The specification only says: [see here, search for "Field presence"](https://www.fixtrading.org/standards/tagvalue-online/#message-structure)

> A tag (field) must appear at most once in a message, except when the
> tag appears within a repeating group.
>
> A tag (field) must appear at most once per repeating group instance.

Comment: So... the conclusion is.. It is allowed by standard, but there are broken implementations which force us to avoid using a nice feature... :( Right?

Comment: @kan I disagree with Christoph John. See my answer in this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56524842/does-quickfix-n-support-messages-containing-two-components-with-one-group-each/

Comment: Didn't you say it worked in QFJ? I do not see the big improvement this would have, though.

Comment: @CiaranMcHale the spec I refer to actually supersedes FIX4.4 and 5.0 spec and I cannot find the paragraph you mentioned in the newest spec I linked. I don't know if reverse-engineering data dictionaries is the right way to prove your point. ;)

Comment: @Christoph John: In essence, the latest spec you link to is inconsistent with earlier specifications. Since at least some FIX implementations will be based on the more restrictive earlier specifications, it seems prudent for somebody writing a data dictionary to respect those more restrictive earlier specifications, since doing that will provide better portability across FIX implementations.

Comment: @Christoph John: A closer reading of the newest specification you linked to leads me to think that it is just badly worded but consistent with the earlier specifications. In particular, the specification states the following (in addition to what you quoted): "Each field is uniquely identified by an integer, known as a tag. Tags must be unique among both session and application message fields. (Fields in the standard header and standard trailer components are shared by session and application messages.)" The relevant wording is "Tags must be unique among [...] message fields."

Comment: @CiaranMcHale actually the document says "Tags must be unique among both session and application message fields" and the ellipsis "Tags must be unique among [...] message fields." is in my opinion not correct. The real intention is to forbid that a tag is at the same time defined as part of the body as well as the header/trailer. To speak in data dictionary terms: you must not have tag n in the `<header>`/`<trailer>` section as well as in the `<messages>` section.

Comment: I think we can agree that the wording is confusing. However, if you search for occurrences of *session* in the spec, you will see that "session = header/trailer field" is not the intended meaning. Rather a *session* message is one in which `msgcat="admin"`, and *application* message is one in which `msgcat="app"`. As such, I believe my use of ellipsis to be correct.

Comment: _Tags must be unique among [...] message fields._ - sounds weird in the context of repeating group scenario.

Comment: @CiaranMcHale well, what should I say. Specifications get superseded and changed all the time, especially in IT. So either you are correct and they *forgot* to mention this exception in the newer spec or I am correct and this is indeed a change that was done intentionally. Either way, I will clarify this with FIX Trading Community and report back. BTW, downvoting because you don't agree with the answer seems a little strange to me because my answer contains references to official specs and as the OP reported it even works with QuickFIX/J.

Comment: @kan I agree. The wording is horribly confusing/inconsistent, and I look forward to Christoph John getting clarification on this.

Comment: @Christoph John I downvoted your answer because I believe it to be incorrect. If you get clarification from the FIX Trading Community that supports your answer, then please update your answer with the relevant information, and I will change my downvote to an upvote (assuming StackOverflow permits that). QuickFIX/J is just one of many implementations of FIX; I know of two other implementations that kan's data dictionary would not work with (one is an in-house FIX engine that generates bad invalid C++ code, and the other is a not-yet-released FIX data dictionary compiler I have developed).

Comment: @CiaranMcHale , I eventually found the time to update my answer. Turned out you were right and I misunderstood the paragraph from the tag-value spec document. However, I compiled some information and hope that it is helpful nevertheless.

Comment: Thanks for providing that update. StackOverflow permitted me to change my downvote to an upvote. @kan I suggest you accept Christoph John's updated answer, since it provides useful reasoning to explain the restriction and the confusing wording in the specification.

Comment: Thanks @CiaranMcHale, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not allowed. I suggest you get a large data dictionary from [http://www.quickfixengine.org](http://www.quickfixengine.org/), save it to your computer in XML format, and then execute a command like the following:

```
grep Price FIX.xml | grep number
```

Doing that will show you the definitions of all the Price-related fields. If you search for each of those field names within messages/components, you will see that each one is used in a different place. The overall result is that each field is listed only once in a message.

Comment: I am asking about building my own data dictionary. I could create a user-defined field like `MyPrice` for that. So, my question not about the `Price` field specifically, but about FIX protocol design and what kind of message structure I could have.

Comment: @kan Unfortunately, many FIX data dictionary compilers do incomplete validation checking, which means if your data dictionary contains an error, the error might not be detected.

Answer (score 0):

You can't re-use a repeating group tag outside a repeating group.

The declaration of a tag as a repeating group tag puts constraints on it, such as its order within a group and how one occurrence is treated differently to a subsequent occurrence.  Non-repeating group tags have no such constraint.

Comment: I have tried with QuickfixJ and it works fine. Is there any specification which forbids it? Because from technical point of view there is no problem to do it.

Comment: Did you only try to create such a Data Dictionary or also to parse such messages?

Comment: @ChristophJohn Yes, I've built a dictionary, generated java classes, created a FIX message and parsed it back. It was working fine for me.